# jQuery how to append after floating divs

Tags: jquery

I have many floating divs in a container div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="c">1</div>
    <div class="c">1</div>
    <div class="c" id="t">1</div>
    <div class="c">1</div>
    <div class="c">1</div>
</div>
```

I am using this styles:

```
<style>
    .container{position:absolute;width:1000px;height:200px;}
    .c {width:250px;float:left;}
</style>
```

Now how can I add element after the element with id "t" using jQuery and referencing the element with id "t" and not using the parent as a reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `insertAfter` or `after`?

Comment: What have your tried and what is not working?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/after/  - Check the jQuery documentation first, it's amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$('<div class="c">2</div>').insertAfter('#t')
```

See the [insertAfter Jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
$('<element />').insertAfter('#t');
```